# How to map Date/time field to Date field?

Tags: apex, datetime

While inserting Event Records am Mapping `ActivityDateTime` to custom date field called `Meeting_Date__c` but it's not inserting.

```
objEvent.ActivityDateTime = objIDReviewMeetingID.ID_Review_Meeting__r.Meeting_Date__c;
```

can any one guide me how to map this fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the Date/time field by using the below code:

```
Date meetingDate = objIDReviewMeetingID.ID_Review_Meeting__r.Meeting_Date__c;
objEvent.ActivityDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(meetingDate.year(), meetingDate.month(),meetingDate.day());
```